# Can't include socket.io.js file in my angular ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I included socket.io.js and app.js file in index.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:8100/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

In app.js i have coded

```
var express = require('express');
var app1     = express();
var server  = app1.listen(8100);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

But when i run the app using ionic serve,the file at socket.io.js cant be found and consequently require function is not defined.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

My app path is like this

```
http://localhost:8100/#/tab/home
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: app.js should be run on node.js server ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma This is a normal ionic project.Will i include the file structure? I created this project using ionic create myApp on the terminal on ubuntu

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the code you have written in app.js?

Comment: Mukesh is right - do not include your app.js in your clientside-code.

Comment: @Molda What you are telling is probably right but the socket.io file is not found firstly.Why is this happening?

Comment: So are you getting error that socket.io.js is not found in browser? Also the code you have is meant for server so remove it from js/app.js.  To connect to server from browser you simply use `var socket = io();` and then you can do ` socket.emit('hello');` or setup listnener `socket.on('Blah',funct....);`

Comment: @Molda thank you so much for cheking in . yes i have written `<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` in index.html but is showing not found error

Comment: @Molda if you can please help me with this error i think i can manage the rest

Comment: OK so do you have a server running with socket.io?

Comment: @Molda yes i do have installed with npm install socket.io --save

Comment: @Molda i think i have managed to include the socket.io file.I had to put the file under www folder.But now it is saying connection is refused.Do you know why this is happening

Comment: Ok i probably understand what you're doing. So if I'm right then remove `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` from index.html and instead run it with node. To do that open terminal in folder with app.js( it should be in root of your project not in public  js folder) and then `node app.js

Comment: @Molda sorry actually the including part is still not solved.The problem i am facing is that i cannot include the socket.io js file

Comment: @Debojyoti placing socketio file to www folder will not solve anything. You need to setup socket server on different port then your ionic app runs on, e.g. 8000 and from ionic app connect to that port using `var socket = new io.Socket(); socket.connect('http://localhost:8000')`

Comment: @Molda can you tell me where to write the app.js server side page.Will it be under www folder?And how can i setup the socket server on a different port?From what i know the code has to be written in app.js which you tell me where to place?maybe inside www folder?

Comment: The best would be to put it to new folder outside your ionic app so if your ionic is in d:/some/path/ionic-app then create new folder for server in d:/some/path/server and place app.js in there

Comment: @Molda But if the app is in google play then the app.js file will be included?

Comment: No app.js is your server it has nothing to do with the ionic application. You will obviously need to run a server where your app will connect using socketio

Comment: If you have some functionality in js/app.js needed for ionic app then create new app.js for server

Comment: @Molda so you are saying the the only server file is the app.js file which will be placed in my server.And i have to connect to the app.js file from my ionic project

Comment: @Molda i understood what you said but why is the socket.io file not included?The file will be included in the index.html file and when i run the project using ionic serve the error is show as 404 not found

Comment: Yes. Place the code you show in question `var express=.....` to server app.js and change the port to 8000 in `listen` and run it `node app.js`. socketio will serve the socket.io.js file for you, you don't need to care about that. And from ionic connect to localhost:8000

Comment: Also change port to 8000 in this link *<script src="http://localhost:8100/socket.io/socket.io.js">*

Comment: @Molda I have added the app.js file in a folder named projectServer.Is there any other files that i have to include as well inside this folder?

Comment: It depends on what functionality you expect from your server but for now it should be fine. You need to run npm install socket.io in serverProject folder otherwise you get an error.

Comment: @Molda i did that and no files were added inside the folder this was the lines in the terminal  `root@brainium:/home/brainium/workspace/serverKrimson# npm install socket.io`
workspace@0.0.1 /home/brainium/workspace
`-- module@0.0.1  extraneous

Comment: @Molda please this is taking too much time can you please upload a git sample folder using ionic or am i asking too much?i have executed it where the url is poining to the socket site chatroom demo.I just cant get my head around it.

Comment: I'm on the my phone now so can't do much but i can upload a sample later, in 2 hours maybe.

Comment: @Molda many thanks for your help for all this time.You cannot know how much i am thankful.I have understood what was the problem.I changed the script src in index.html like <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>It is the path to the client socket url.The server socket can be used by just npm install

Comment: @Molda I have executed the app.js file on the folder projectServer.And it is emiting a message.But now how will i run the ionic app?Because i have to use the terminal to execute the ionic app

Comment: You can open as many terminals as you wish :)

Comment: @Molda never knew :). Ok i got the basic understanding right and now i will expand on this thing.Thanks for the help that you gave me.I will in the future write a blog about this and thank you in that blog.You stayed for me for 6 hours and thank you for that very much